# Super Resolution on text documents

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I want to implement super-resolution and deblurring on images from text documents. Which is the best approach? Are there any Git-hub links which will help me to start? I am new to the field. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have heard of super-resolution and deblurring of images, but I've never heard of super-resolution or deblurring of text documents. Where did you hear of these expressions?

Comment: @nbro I mean applying the techniques on document images i.e. My interest is on textual information on the image.

Comment: Hi. Just edit your post to clarify these points!

Comment: @deep_learner do you mean to step 1) extract text from image, step 2) essentially autocorrect/autocomplete text ???

Comment: Here ya are: https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance